# никак не могу исправить ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

ошибка :

```
PS C:\Users\chupr_om\Desktop\dz2> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
 File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\chupr_om\Desktop\dz2\one\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
from views import my_model_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No mo
```

settings.py:
Django settings for one project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-n3k6c%&s8#1*p46-mau6@zzg3(zp7vmy0yxo_q52c-augf!4-6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',     
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'one.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'one.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
  }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
```

urls.py:

```
"""
URL configuration for one project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.urls import path
from views import file1, file2, file3


urlpatterns = [
   path('file1/', file1),
   path('file2/', file2),
   path('file3/', file3),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MyModel

def my_model_view(request):
   my_models = MyModel.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'my_models': my_models})

def file1(request):
   return FileResponse(open('images/1.jpeg', 'rb'))

def file2(request):
   return FileResponse(open('images/2.jpg', 'rb'))

def file3(request):
   return FileResponse(open('images/3.jpg', 'rb'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Из текста ошибки логично, что нужно в первую очередь смотреть файл `dz2\one\urls.py`